# Load all tables of a database in a single dataset

Tags: c#, ado.net, dataset

I am learning ADO.Net [C#] and want to fill different DataGridViews with the DataGridView.DataSource = DataSet.tables[] command.
But i only know how to fill 1 table to 1 data adapter, is it possible to query the whole database and put all the tables in a single dataset so i can use the dataset.tables[table index] option to fill till the datagridview?

Example:

```
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source =.accdb";

        ds = new DataSet();
        da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * ", con);
        da.Fill(ds);
        dgv.DataSource = ds.Tables[0]; (i want to have all the tables as an index so that i can put this as the datasource of the datagridview).
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. By "table" do you mean a System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView table, a System.Data.DataTable instance, or a physical database table?

Comment: They are specifically referring to tables in a database and `DataTables` in a `DataSet`, as stated in the last sentence of their question.

Comment: i mean that i want to set all the physical database tables to 1 single data adapter,wich i can use for my datagridview sources.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you can tell the DataAdapter to return multiple result sets, by giving it multiple SELECT queries, separated by a semilcolon, like so:

```
da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Table1; SELECT * FROM Table2", con);
```

In addition, you can fill a DataSet using multiple DataAdapters, like so:

```
daTable1 = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Table1", con);
daTable2 = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Table2", con);
daTable1.Fill(ds, "Table1");
daTable2.Fill(ds, "Table2");
```

You should then be able to access the tables in your DataSet via indexers.  Specifically [ds.Tables[int index]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cfsd7dz4.aspx) and [ds.Tables[String name]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58st33fb.aspx), like so:

`dgv.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];` or `dgv.DataSource = ds.Tables["Table1"];`

For more info, see [MSDN - Populating a DataSet from a DataAdapter (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh8kx08z.aspx)
 (sepcifically *Multiple Result Sets* and *Populating a DataSet from Multiple DataAdapters*).

Comment: I'm not sure if you can just select all tables in your database.  I would lean towards no, you probably need to specify which tables you need.

Comment: thankyou for replying, for my exam yesterday i had to fill like 12 gridviews with all the data from a table so i used the method you mentioned second use a new adapter for each table and fill the set with the adapter.fill().but the code was getting pretty long, so i was just wondering if like i questioned it was possible to select them all, my teacher said yes, it should be possible but he diddnt know how, maybe someone else?

Comment: I'd imagine it's *possible*, but it would probably involve querying the sys DB and building a giant select statement on the fly.  Sounds dangerous and hacky to me.

Comment: How about 1st query to show all table names, then iterating over all results construct dynamically something like this `String.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}",TableName);`?

Never tried it but I can't think of a reason why wouldn't it work.

Comment: That would definitely work, although you'd be loading your entire database into memory.  Depending on the size of your project, doing something like that could be very costly, especially if you only end up using a few of those tables.  For the situation posed here, I would recommend just creating a function that takes a table name, creates a DataAdapter to retrieve that table, and then returns a filled DataTable.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use this easy way.
with this way you can add as many table as you like.

```
string str = @"SELECT INV_ID,INV_CLIENTNAME,INV_ADD1,INV_CITY,INV_TEL,INV_CIF,INV_DATE,INV_DISCOUNT,
                           ITEM_DES,ITEM_QTY,ITEM_PRICE,INV_TAX_PERCENT,ITEM_QTY*ITEM_PRICE as gtotal
                          FROM (tbl_client INNER JOIN tbl_item ON tbl_client.INV_ID = tbl_item.FK_INV_ID)
                          WHERE (tbl_client.INV_ID = 'abc123')";

 OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(str, cn.db_cn);
 DataSet dset = new DataSet();
 adp.Fill(dset,"DataTable1");

str = @"SELECT company_name, company_address, company_city, company_tel, company_cif, Id FROM tbl_info";

adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(str, cn.db_cn);

adp.Fill(dset, "tbl_info");
```